# Upgrading EF6 to EF Core 3 with Devart.MySql

Tags: mysql, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6, devart, dotconnect

I've been trying to upgrade our Entity Framework from EF6 to EF Core 3.1 and I get this weird error.

So here are the steps that I did or some info that might help

- Current .NET framework version is 4.7.2
- Using EF Core 6
- Using MySQL
- Upgrade EF Core to EF Core 3.1 (Why 3.1? We can't upgrade the class library version yet as it has a lot of dependencies and 3.1 is latest compatible version with .NET 4.7.2)
- I'm using Devart dotConnect for MySql as provider. Also upgraded to version 8.19 (latest as of the moment)
- Fixed all build errors and created model builders to define and map table properties and columns.

After doing all those steps, project builds without errors and project runs. However when I try to login (which obviously does a database call), it stalls. If I place a breakpoint on the actual linq query, it stalls. It does nothing. No timeout error, no exceptions, just nothing. Also I tried to check the database server log, query was not logged so definitely query didn't go through the server. I also tried to purposely put a wrong db name on the connection string, it threw an error, database didnt exist.

Anyone experienced the same?

Answer (score 0):

1. Enable the dbMonitor tool to check if the connection is opened and SQL query is sent to MySQL Server: https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/?dbmonitor.html. Is there any error?
2. Before debugging your project, make these settings in your Visual Studio to get an exception and detailed stack trace:

- in the (Debug > Windows > Exception Settings) window, select Common Language Runtime Exceptions
- in the (Tools > Options) window, navigate to Debugging > General and clear Enable Just My Code

If this doesn't help to fix the issue, please submit your request via [our contact form](https://www.devart.com/company/contactform.html) for getting support.